# javascript directing to back to the page using onclick function

Tags: php, javascript, forms, redirect, submit

I am trying to direct back to a page "jerseyCollection" if there is no value on price of total shop. Here is the code. I am including all the code because I think there is something crashing with onclick="checkOrder()" function which contains code to redirect user back to order page. Here is the code for function. I know checkOrder() works because I have tried it with alert and i know redirecting statement works because I have tried it in other pages, too. But I just can't figure it out why it is not directing back to the shopping page even with no value in total shopping value..
Please help me figure this out. and how to solve this.

```
function checkOrder(){
var x = document.choice.realTotal.value 
    if (x == false){
        alert ("Please do the shopping");
        window.location.href='jerseyCollection.php';
    }
}

<

    !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Jersey Collection</title>
        <link href="general.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                    border: 4px solid #333333; 
                    width: 80%;    
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto; }
            td {
                    padding: 8px;
                    border 1px solid #333333;
                    background-color: #ccc; 
                    text-align: center; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="general.js" />
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
       <div>
        <div id="sidebar">
                <div style="color:#CCC">
                    <h2><a href="index.html">James' NBA Jersey Shop</a></h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                <FORM>
                    <p><INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Personal Info" ONCLICK="window.location.href='personalInfo.php'" /></p> 
                    <p><INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Jersey Collection" ONCLICK="window.location.href='jerseyCollection.php'" disabled /></p>
                    <p><INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Confirmation" ONCLICK="window.location.href='confirmation.php'" disabled /></p>
                    <p><INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Order" ONCLICK="window.location.href='order.html'" /></p>
                    <br>
                    <p><INPUT Type="reset" VALUE="Reset Order Info" /></p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p>Web Style Option</p>
                    <p><input name ="stylish" value="DGH" onclick="styleChange('DGH')" type="radio" checked="true" />Dark Gray & Gray & Helvetica</p> 
                    <p><input name ="stylish" value="RON" onclick="styleChange('RON')" type="radio" />Red & Orange & New York</p>  
                    <p><input name ="stylish" value="SBC" onclick="styleChange('SBC')" type="radio" />Sky Blue & Blue & Comic Sans</p> 

                </FORM>
                </div>
            </div>
    <div id="contents">
        <div>
            <h1 class="title">Jersey Collection</h1>      
        </div>
        <form name="choice" action="http://i6.cims.nyu.edu/~jwj243/Assignment5/confirmation.php" method="post">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="atlanta_josh_smith.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
                <td><img src="boston_paul_pierce.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
                <td><img src="brooklyn_deron_williams.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
                <td><img src="chicago_derrick_rose.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price: $20<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_ajs_20" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value= 
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $PROD_ajs_20; else echo 0;  ?> ></td>
                <td>Price: $25<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_bpp_25" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) print $PROD_bpp_25; else echo 0;  ?> ></td>
                <td>Price: $25<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_bdw_25" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) print $PROD_bdw_25; else echo 0; ?> ></td>
                <td>Price: $30<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_cdr_30" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) print $PROD_cdr_30; else echo 0; ?> ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="houston_jeremy_lin.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
                <td><img src="la_blake_griffin.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
                <td><img src="la_kobe_bryant.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
                <td><img src="miami_dwyane_wade.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price: $25<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_hjl_25" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $PROD_hjl_25; else echo 0; ?>  ></td>
                <td>Price: $30<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_lbg_30" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $PROD_lbg_30; else echo 0; ?>  ></td>
                <td>Price: $30<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_lkb_30" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $PROD_lkb_30; else echo 0; ?>  ></td>
                <td>Price: $30<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_mdw_30" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $PROD_mdw_30; else echo 0; ?>  ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="miami_lebron_james.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
                <td><img src="ny_carmelo_anthony.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
                <td><img src="okc_kevin_durant.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
                <td><img src="orlando_dwight_howard.jpg" width="200" height="200"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price: $35<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_mlj_35" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $PROD_mlj_35; else echo 0; ?>  ></td>
                <td>Price: $35<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_nca_35" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $PROD_nca_35; else echo 0; ?>  ></td>
                <td>Price: $35<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_okd_35" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $PROD_okd_35; else echo 0; ?>  ></td>
                <td>Price: $30<br>Quantity<input name="PROD_odh_30" id="q" size=2 type="text" onChange = "calculateTotal(this.form)" value=
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $PROD_odh_30; else echo 0; ?>  ></td>

            </tr>            

        </table>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total: <input type="text" id ="realTotal" name="realTotal" size=2 value = <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])) echo $realTotal; ?> ></td>
                    <td><span name="order_total" id="order_total" style="text-align: right; font-size: 20px">$0.00</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type= "submit" value="Next" onclick="checkOrder()" ><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value ="true" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </form>
     <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>   
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did some snooping, `sorry`. Why not check if `total=0` on `confirmation.php`?

Comment: Could you elaborate it, please..? The problem I am having is that when I have no data for document.choice.realTotal.value, statement redirecting to another page is not working.. alert function that is inside the same if statement is working, so I don't think if statement has any problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkOrder(){
    var x = document.choice.realTotal.value;
    if (x == false){
        alert ("Please do the shopping");
        window.location.href='jerseyCollection.php';
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your code, the submit button looks like this:

`<td><input type= "submit" value="Next" onclick="checkOrder()" ><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value ="true" /></td>`

Please change it to:

`<td><input type= "submit" value="Next" onclick="return checkOrder()" ><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value ="true" /></td>`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked that if statement is working with original, so alert does appear with the original function.. redirecting is what is not working...

Comment: To stop a form from submitting, you need to `return false` on the submit button. That means that if it fails, it should return the function that returns false.

Comment: I feel like <form action=~~~ /> has something to do with it, but I can't figure it out. I feel like redirection command and <form action> is clashing or something..

Comment: Have you replaced your submit button with the above code? Onclick needs to return false if you want to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: you mean I should return false right under window.location ??

Comment: function checkOrder(){
var x = document.choice.realTotal.value 
 if (x == false){
  alert ("Please do the shopping");
  window.location.href="jerseyCollection.php";
  
  return false
 }
}

Comment: it is showing the alert message, but not taking me back to the page I want them to direct user...

Comment: Can you find `<input type= "submit" value="Next" onclick="checkOrder()" >` in your code?

Comment: <input type= "submit" value="Next" onClick="checkOrder()" > this is what I have right now

Comment: Change it to `<input type= "submit" value="Next" onclick="return checkOrder()" >`.

Comment: Can I ask you another question?

Comment: This webpage has another page for personal information. user can fill out the form and the page is supposed to save those information as cookie and print them in confirmation page.. but it does not seem to be doing it when I go through the shopping information..

Comment: can I send you the file I have so you can take a look?

Comment: Please update the question above to include the code from `personal information page` and `confirmation page`.

Comment: I am building a shopping cart webpage, but it has been very rough a couple weeks.. it literally has been taking over 40 hours.. AT LEAST

Comment: I don't see the `codes` on the original question. This is getting a bit cluttered. Why not accept my question and open another?

Comment: I did open another one with all the file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411666/printing-out-personal-info-stored-as-cookie-and-session-php